# What type does `import * as Thing from '...'` make?

Tags: javascript, es6-module-loader, es6-modules

What type does `import * as MyModule from 'module-name'` create?

I'm assuming it's a normal javascript object with the keys being the names of the exported values but I don't know for sure.

Example:

`./module-that-exports.js`

```
export const a = 'foo';
export const b = 'bar';
```

`./module-that-imports.js`

```
import * as thing from './module-that-exports';

typeof thing; // what does this print? what is its type?
```

---

specifically, i'm using webpack. i don't know if that makes a difference.

Comment: Why not try it?

Comment: That's a script you can test yourself right? I assume it's just an object. And it will be as long it is transpiled. Which it will, because no browser currently has native support for it.

Comment: @SimpleJ that would require setting up a webpack project or something and i got work to do lol. i thought asking here could probably help someone else who is asking the same question or something.

Comment: It's all on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's an object (and not callable), so `typeof` will yield `"object"`.

However, it is not an ordinary object, it's an exotic [module namespace object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-module-namespace-exotic-objects). It does not inherit from `Object.prototype`, it is not [extensible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isExtensible), and all its properties are non-writable getters that resolve to the exported bindings. Your transpiler/module loader may not be able to completely emulate this though.

Comment: exactly what i was looking for. thanks for the spec references

Answer (score 1):

So let's say you've got one file:

```
const doSomething = () => console.log('hello');
const doSomethingElse = () => console.log('world');

export default {
    doSomething,
    doSomethingElse
}
```

and you've got another file that uses it. You don't want to name all the fields, so instead of doing that, you group them in an object.

```
import * as something from './doSomething'
```

That will create an object that contains the two functions..

```
console.log(something);
```

Will print:

```
{
    doSomething: function() { ... }
    doSomethingElse: function() { ... }
}
```

The advantage of this is you don't need some long import, just use the `something` object.

```
something.doSomething();
something.toSomethingElse();
```